# How to reset the Observable interval operator in RXSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm new in RXSwift and i defined an Observable interval timer sequence that calls a webservice method every second.
In that webservice response, i receive new retry time value that must replace with my current time.
How to reset this sequence with new time value?
This is my code :

```
func mySequence() {

    /////////////////////////////////////// subscribe to Timer (time change)
    var time = try! self.timer.value()

    self.disposeTimer = timer.subscribe({  value in

        time = value.element!

        print("=============================\(String(describing: time))=======================================")

    })
    /////////////////////////////////////// subscribe to Timer (time change)


    let   observable = Observable<Int>.interval(TIME I NEED TO CHANGE After response , scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).map { _ in ()
        self.myWebserviceMethod()
    }

    disposable =  observable.subscribe(onNext: {num in

    }, onError: { err in

    }, onCompleted: {

    }, onDisposed: {

    })

}
```

everything happens but interval timer time is still the old value :(

Comment: Just remove(dispose) old subscription and make new subscription with new interval

Comment: Can you edit my code?where should i dispose?timer is observable and it’ not disposable.can you send me a sample ?

Comment: Every subscription of any observable sequence is disposable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove(dispose) old subscription and make new subscription with new interval

```
var timerDisposable:Disposable?
var retryTime:RxTimeInterval = 1

func stratRefresh() {
    timerDisposable?.dispose()
    timerDisposable = Observable<Int>
        .timer(0, period: retryTime, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { value in
            myWebserviceMethod()
        })
}

func myWebserviceMethod() {
    // In service response update your retryTime
    // Ex.
    APIClient.getRetryTime() { newTime in
        if retryTime != newTime {
            retryTime = newTime
            stratRefresh()
        }
    }
}
```